# How to Create One Form Only in Rails to Submit two things Simple Form Carrier Wave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, simple-form

I am currently building a rails platform like a Reddit style type of community for international students in the Boston area. I am still testing the reception of my idea. I am using simple form and carrierwave. I got this `@student = Student.new` instance in my signup method. I got this `@uploader = Student.new.picture` in my signup method as well (using carrierwave). The idea is that every student has a picture associated to him or her. I got a carrierwave's picture feature mounted on my student model. I am using carrierwave_direct gem to directly upload the pictures to my s3 storage on amazon.

My signup.html.erb looks like this

```
<div class = "signupform">

    <%= simple_form_for @student, :html => {:multipart => true}  do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :last_name, label: '姓'%>
    <%= f.input :first_name, label: '名' %>
    <%= f.input :email, label: '电子邮件' %>
    <%= f.input :password, label: '密码' %>
    <%= f.input :college, label: '大学' %>
    <%= f.input :budget, label: '房间租金预算 (optional)' %> 
    <%= f.button :submit %>
    <br>

    Your picture is optional
    <% end %>

    <%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f| %>
      <p><%= f.file_field :picture %></p>
    <%= f.button :submit %>

  <% end %>

</div>
```

How do I make this into one form? I have two submit buttons on my form, where the user can create an account but get redirected to a thank you page or the user can just upload a picture and not create an account?

The direct_upload_form_for is directly is a helper view method from carrier direct which is needed to upload directly to s3 I suppose ?

Comment: I don't think you can submit two completely different form without some js magic.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using two forms instead of one form? Include the image upload in the student model.

```
<%= simple_form_for @student, :html => {:multipart => true}  do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :last_name, label: '姓'%>
    <%= f.input :first_name, label: '名' %>
    <%= f.input :email, label: '电子邮件' %>
    <%= f.input :password, label: '密码' %>
    <%= f.input :college, label: '大学' %>
    <%= f.input :budget, label: '房间租金预算 (optional)' %> 

    <%= f.file_field :picture, label: 'student photo (optional)' %>   

    <%= f.button :submit %>
    <br>
```

Can you call the helper method simple_form? If you need to form it this way what about

```
<%= simple_form_for @student, :html => {:multipart => true}  do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :last_name, label: '姓'%>
    <%= f.input :first_name, label: '名' %>
    <%= f.input :email, label: '电子邮件' %>
    <%= f.input :password, label: '密码' %>
    <%= f.input :college, label: '大学' %>
    <%= f.input :budget, label: '房间租金预算 (optional)' %> 

    <%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f| %>
     <p><%= f.file_field :picture %></p>

    <%= f.button :submit %>
    <br>
```